# Concat all remotely distributed files in your cluster

Tags: bash, ssh, files, scp, cat

I want to concatenate all abc_2015-12-15.txt  files present on my cluster.Is there any best way to achieve this ?

One way is to use below command across all nodes till all files concatenated :-

```
ssh root@node1 "cat >> /home/abc/abc_2015-12-15.txt" < /home/abc/abc_2015-12-15.txt
```

What is the fastest way to concatenate in distributed environment.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to collect the files locally, then do the concatenation, if you need the end result to be a single file.

Ansible is a great tool for performing tasks across clusters, and has a module for fetching remote files (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/fetch_module.html), although the initial learning curve can be a bit of a barrier.

If command line interaction is easier to grasp, and you can install a Python utility, RadSSH (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/radssh) has some quick ways to gather files either individually (*get /home/abc/abc-2015-12-15.txt) or as tarfiles (*tgz /home/abc/abc-2015-12-15.txt), among other tricks.